# Error when using AUTO_INCREMENT in TablePlus

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, table-plus

I was following a tutorial for Laravel and this course required me to use TablePlus.
I had to create a table with a given query, but it's not working and I am not completely sure as to why it's not working.

Here is the query I am using

```
CREATE TABLE users {
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
};
```

In the tutorial I am following "Auto_Increment" is highlighted blue, but with me it's just the standard white.

And this is the error I receive when I try to run this query.

```
Query 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `email` VAR' at line 1
```

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me why this is happening as it is something that Google doesn't have answer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making an error using {}
TRY:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);
```

Or is it because of `laravel`?
I am not sure about laravel

Comment: I completely missed that. Thank you!